# CloudSQL, WHEN to increase RAM?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

In Google CloudSql you cannot monitor RAM, and as far as I can tell, you cannot monitor disk/cache usage.

So when do you decide to increase RAM? When users complain it's slow?
Slow queries counter increases? Number of aborted connections?
Just follow my guts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query in your mysql instance:

```
show global status like 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_PAGES_%';
```

Then look at the "Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free" and "Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total" variable to see how many pages are free compare to how many pages are allocated to your instance. Each page is 16KB.